# jmeter use multiple BeanShell PostProcessor parametrs in http request

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, beanshell

Could anyony explain how to do such task?

In my testStep I have a BeanShell PostProcessor.
It returns a list of n elements. (each time number of elemets is different)
I wonder, is it possible to run some equal http requests that will use that elements?

for example,
Processor returned var1,var2,var3
then it'd be three http request:

```
  .../get-smth$var=var1
  .../get-smth$var=var2
  .../get-smth$var=var3
```

I realised that I'd use a size in order to put it as variable in loop controller, but how to apply variables to http request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leo, probably an array + a foreach controller can solve your problem. Take a look at [this section of the JMeter manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller.)

Regarding the variables, you can include almost anywhere... for example, if you want to include var1 into your resquest; just refer it as ${var1}. Something like http://mydomain/doSomethingWith.php?variable=${var1}
Also pay attention to multidimensional variables (arrays); ie
var1_1 will give you the first element

Comment: thanks a lot, solved!) BeanShell PostProcessor returns var_1,var_2,...var_2 and  ForEach Controller uses that as well.